# Get record's age in seconds if older than 5 minutes (otherwise 0) in Django (with PostgreSQL database)

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm retrieving all records, and I would like to display the record's age for those records that are older than 5 minutes.

The output should be something like this (in this example, two records: `1.8.9.1` and `2.7.3.1` are older than 5 minutes) :

```
ip       ...  status
---------------------
1.8.9.1  ...  3 hours
2.7.3.1  ...  7 minutes
1.1.1.1  ...  up
1.1.1.2  ...  up
1.1.1.3  ...  up
1.1.1.4  ...  up
1.1.1.5  ...  up
```

Here's my current code:

```
Interfaces.objects.all()
.annotate(
  age = (datetime.utcnow() - F('timestamp')), # 0:00:08.535704
  age2 = Epoch(datetime.utcnow() - F('timestamp')), # 8.535704
  # age3 = int(Epoch(datetime.utcnow() - F('timestamp'))/300),
  current_time=Value(str(datetime.utcnow()),
                       output_field=null_char_field),
)
.order_by('age','ip')
```

`age` and `age2` both work, but the problem is that I want the records that are older than 5 minutes sorted by `age`, and the rest by `ip`

So I'm trying to set `age` to `0`, if it's less than 5 minutes.

If I would do it directly in postgresql, I'd use this query:

```
select ip, <other fields>,
   case when extract('epoch' from now() - "timestamp") > 300
        then extract('epoch' from now() - "timestamp")
        else 0
   end
```

Is there a way to do it in django?

Comment: If you're getting "all records" anyway, one option is to simply use `all()` and do whatever sorting and organizing you want in Python.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out:

```
Interfaces.objects.all()
.annotate(
   age=Case(
          When(timestamp__lt=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=5),
               then=Cast(Epoch(datetime.utcnow() - F('timestamp')),
                         NullIntegerField)),
          default=0,
          output_field=NullIntegerField
   ),
)
.order_by('age','ip')
```

By the way, my imports and relevant settings:

```
from django.db.models import  F, Func, Case, When, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce, Cast

NullIntegerField = IntegerField(null=True)

class Epoch(Func):
    function = 'EXTRACT'
    template = "%(function)s('epoch' from %(expressions)s)"
```

This website ended up being the most helpful: https://micropyramid.com/blog/django-conditional-expression-in-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in other way also which will be faster.
Get current time, subtract from that 5 minutes, after that search all the Interfaces
where age is less or equal than the subtracted date.

example:

```
current_time = datetime.now()
older_than_five = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

Interfaces.objects.all()
.annotate(
   age=Case(
       When(age__lt=older_than_five, then=Value(0)),
       default=F('age')
   )
)
.order_by('age','ip')
```

Comment: I need to display all records, not just the old ones

Comment: The query that i wrote should display all records that are 5 minutes and older.
What do you mean by **display all records, not just the old ones** ?

Comment: your query displays all records that are 5 minutes and older. by "all records" I mean also those records that are less than 5 minutes old.

Comment: Try it now and see if its the desired result.

Comment: That's kind of like what I did 2 days ago. I already got it working. (See my answer) But thanks for trying.

Comment: @GrannyAching your right, but i didnt like the EPOCH aproach thats why i did this, anyway both should do the job.

Comment: That is true, `EPOCH` is postgreSQL specific. And your latest edits make it seem to work the same as mine, thus being more elegant. When I have some time (haha) I will test your version. But for now, mine seems to be working.